# Google Maps: Prevent collaborators from affecting each other's polygons

Tags: api, google-maps, collaboration

**Background:**

I'm organizing a massive food drive for the scouts.  Scout units are made up of families with a unit organizer.  I've created a custom map to allow each unit to define their own food drive outreach areas, and I've invited unit organizers to collaborate on the map.  Each unit organizer can in turn invite individuals from within their respective units to define the areas they will cover.  The idea of the map is to help the collaborators prevent overlapping outreach areas.

**Question:**
How can I prevent the collaborators from affecting each other's polygons on the custom map?

I thought of creating a custom map for each unit and then creating a script that would periodically import the kml files into an overarching map that every unit could view but not change.  But there appears to be a limitation on the maps api of only about 10 kml layers, and I've got about 30 units collaborating.  I'm hoping there's a better solution than just having a free-for-all on my custom map.

Comment: How are the users drawing there areas?  Why not just use regular polygons instead of trying to use KML. http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/

Comment: Sounded to me like the Polygons were coming from "MyMaps/MyPlaces" in Google Maps.

Comment: Correct, the users have access to draw the polygons directly on the map because I've added them as collaborators through the My Maps/My Places functionality in Google Maps.  The idea of KML came to me as a means of preventing each unit from affecting other unit's edits.  In that senario each unit would have it's own map, and I'd combine all the shapes of all the maps into one super-map using kmlLayers.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer).  Import the individual KML files into a [FusionTable](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/), display the resulting map using FusionTablesLayer. ([tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)).

It would solve the 10 KML layer limitation, and prevent them from changing other polygons, but wouldn't solve the potential of overlapping polygons.  You would probably need to write code to detect overlapping polygons, them resolve them manually somehow.

Comment: This is a great idea, and one that I've looked into.  Unfortunately it appears that I can only import the KML data into the fusion table at the time the table is created.  Any subsequent updates to their map would not appear in the table.  I'd need some way to empty their table and repopulate it periodically.  Detecting overlapping polygons is not a requirement at this time, it's just something I'd like to at least give the users a shot at preventing on their own by letting them see the polygons that have already been added by other users.

Comment: I've also considered programmatically generating the fusion table from the KML file and periodically destroying it and recreating it again, to keep the data mostly fresh.  I haven't found a way to get the KML data imported programmatically though.  It appears to be only an option to import a KML file through the UI at the time of table creation.